# How to revert last commits on branch, merge with other branch and re-add the commits?

Tags: git

I have the following problem. A git repo was forked a while ago. Starting from this fork, changes were made, but at the same time the original repo was also modified a lot more even, somehow like this:

```
A-B-C-D-E master
   \[fork]
    C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-I'-J'----X' remote/master
```

It is important to note that the fork basically decoupled master and remote/master. The problem now is, I can create a local branch from remote/master and merge it directly with the local master branch. However, this will bring up a lot of merge conflicts which I would like to avoid, because most of these conflicts are related to changes in the main software package before B. So what I eventually would need to do is to take the last few commits of master since the fork and put them on top of the remote/master branch. Is that possible?

Comment: If you have conflicting changes you have to resolve the conflicts

Comment: Yeah, I would like to resolve all conflicts, but only for the things I have added to master since the fork. Because for all other conflicts, I can simply always tell git to prefer the remote/master change, because that is the most current one.

Comment: The operation you are looking for is `git rebase remote/master`. But it will give you the same conflicts that you get with a merge, or even more of them because every single commit can have its own set of conflicts.

Comment: Found a solution and added it below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone comes to this question, I solved the issue by the following procedure:

- Created a new branch containing only all commits A-E and remove the latest commits C-E from the history of master:

  ```
  git checkout master
  git branch new_branch
  git reset --hard HEAD~5

      C-D-E new_branch
     /
  A-B       master
     \[fork]
      C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-I'-J'----X' remote/master
  ```
- Merged the master branch with remote/master accepting all changes from remote/master:

  ```
  git checkout remote/master
  git merge -Xours master

      C-D-E new_branch
     /
  A-B---------------------------      
     \[fork]                    \
      C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-I'-J'----X' remote/master, master
  ```
- Checked-out master and performed a rebase with remote/master

  ```
  git checkout master
  git rebase remote/master

  A-B---------------------------      
     \[fork]                    \
      C'-D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-I'-J'----X' remote/master, master
                                  \
                                   C-D-E new_branch
  ```

Comment: Your original description of the problem must have been inaccurate, because if it were like you showed in the pictures, a content merge would not be required; forwarding `master` to `remote/master` would be a fast-forward operation.

Comment: It would be fast-forward if master and remote/master would have a joined history, but they did not, because of the fork they were basically decoupled. maybe the scheme was not really accurate.

Comment: That is an important aspect, and your drawings do not make this point clear. That said, your solution is reasonable.